# PHP broken relative links in nested directories

Tags: php, directory, path, nested, relative-path

I'm sure I'm missing some simple explanation, but I want to confirm - so assume I know very little.

I have a directory structure like so (for the time being) of:

My main site (localhost/project/ on my testing server, and C:/xampp/htdocs/project on my HDD) with these files and folders:

```
Root
  graphics
    variousgraphics.png

  support
    stylesheet.css


  templates
    header.php
    footer.php
    initialize.php

  you
    default.php

  index.php
  anotherfile.php
```

Up until I created the folder 'you' everything was fine, i.e. I included the initialize file for index.php as `<?php include(templates/initialize.php) ?>`

But when I decide to include initialize.php using the above method for the default.php file (inside 'you'), it errored out with `Warning: include(templates/initialize.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\photoquilt\you\default.php`

So naturally I appended `../` to create `<?php include(../templates/initialize.php) ?>` but then of course that didn't work because the files referenced inside initialize.php weren't appended in the same way, and so I get to here.

It's worth noting for me, an echo of `$_SERVER['document_root']` leads to C:/xampp/htdocs

### So in summary:

Is there any way to make sure all the link/paths work correctly irrespective of where the originating path was from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default.php you can define a constant like

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
```

or for php versions prior to 5.3.0

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

and then use `ROOT_PATH` in all scripts to build the the file paths.

see
- http://docs.php.net/language.constants.predefined
- http://docs.php.net/dirname

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to work at all for me. If in you/default.php I type `define('ROOT_PATH', basename(__DIR__));` and then `include(ROOT_PATH.'/templates/initialize.php')`, I get the same error as I mentioned in my OP, except now it simply says `Warning: include(you/templates/initialize.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\photoquilt\you\default.php`?

Comment: oops, that's because I'm an idiot ;-)   basename->dirname, see updated version of answer...

Comment: Perfect! It does work, but I've had to change some of my links a bit (obviously), so, but how does this differ from using absolute links, aren't we essentially concatenating on the front portion of the file name and then typing the rest out manually? Thanks, upvote!

Comment: Yes, you're now using absolute paths ...more or less. When you use relative paths they are realtive to the current working directory. Now you paths are "relative" to ROOT_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here as far as I can tell: the server-sided and the client-sided.

As for the PHP goes, you are doing it fine. Referencing the file by its relative path (`../templates/initialize.php`) is the way to go. There's another way of achieving the same, though I wouldn't recommend it: editing the include_path to add the root directory of your project. You can do it in an `.htaccess` located in the root directory, ie:

```
php_value include_path ".:/path/to/your/project:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

For the HTML part (images not loading, stylesheets not found), you can set a base href:

```
<base href="http://path.to.your/in-server/" />
```

The base href should point the root of your directory. All the images, stylesheets, etc in HTML must then be fixed to use relative URIs from the root of the project (`graphics/variousgraphics.png`).

Comment: Yes, but referencing `../templates/initialize.php` only moves the problem forward to initialize.php, since the referenced files inside that aren't appended in the same way.